# Python Google Maps API Stopped working

Tags: python, google-maps-api-3

I have some python code that uses the Google Maps API that used to work but now for some reason it returns no results.  Here is my code

```
import simplejson
import urllib
import re

GEOCODE_BASE_URL='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json'

def geocode(address,sensor,**geo_args):
    geo_args.update({
        'address': address,
        'sensor':sensor
        })

    url=GEOCODE_BASE_URL+'?'+urllib.urlencode(geo_args)
    result=simplejson.load(urllib.urlopen(url))
    return simplejson.dumps([s['formatted_address'] for s in result['results']],indent=2)

def main():
    city=geocode(address="toronto",sensor="false")
    print city

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But it shows no results.  I swear it used to work, I don't understand what changed.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: There are no errors. But no results are returned.

Comment: This may help : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/#ParsingJSON

Comment: The URL http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=toronto&sensor=false returns results for me.

Comment: Again, I am getting no results from the code from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/#ParsingJSON even though it says it should return somehting.  I don't get it.  Does anyone else get results from this code?

Comment: OK its magically working again. I didn;t change anything...

Comment: It can happen for some addresses if you don't add country to it.